# How to run a quadratic model with plateau with binary outcome?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, modeling, link-function

I'm trying to build a generalised linear model in which the predicted probability of y follows a quadratic curve but hits a plateau at its maximum.

I have found some solutions for a linear model using the Mistcherlich Curve (https://plantcropmodels.files.wordpress.com/2016/11/growth-models1.pdf), however, I am struggling to find one for glm.

Looking at an example function, using a dataset within R - mtcars - I would want to model vs as a function of mpg but unlike my approach below I would want the predicted probability of vs to plateau at some maximum point. In the example that would would be mpg==32.4 but I expect this to be possibly different if different function is applied (otherwise I'd have just copy that maximum value for all values of mpg >= 32.4

```r
model <- glm(vs ~ poly(mpg,2), data = mtcars, family = "binomial")
summary(model)

temp.data <- expand.grid(mpg = seq(10, 34, 0.1))
temp.data$pred <- predict(model, temp.data, type="response", 
                          allow.new.levels=TRUE)
glimpse(temp.data)
temp.data <- temp.data %>% group_by(mpg) %>% 
          mutate(predprob = mean(pred, na.rm=TRUE))

# which mpg has the highest predicted probability
temp.data[which.max(temp.data$predprob), c("mpg", "predprob")] # 32.4
output <- aggregate(temp.data, by = list(temp.data$mpg), FUN = mean,
                     na.rm=TRUE)
output
output[unique(output$mpg), c("mpg", "predprob")]

reg <- ggplot(temp.data, aes(x=mpg, y=predprob)) + 
  geom_line(color = "black") +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 32.4, color = "darkgrey", 
             linetype = "dotted") +
  scale_x_continuous(name = "mpg", 
                     breaks = seq(10,34,2)) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent, 
                     limits = c(0,1)) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_text(face="bold", size=14),
        axis.text.y = element_text(face="bold", size=12),
        axis.title.x = element_text(size = 16, 
                margin = margin(t = 20, r = 0, b = 10, l = 0)),
        axis.title.y = element_text(size = 16, margin = margin(t = 0, 
                                    r = 20, b = 0, l = 10)),
        legend.title = element_blank(), legend.position = "none") +
  ylab("Probability of vs")
reg
```

[image: function][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1T9pk.png)

Comment: Please explain to us what exactly you mean by a "quadratic curve."  Would that perhaps include the inverse logit function used by many generalized linear models?

Comment: I meant the predictor (x) : ln(p/1-p) = a + bx^2

Comment: That will plateau at its maxima, which occur where $|x|$ grows arbitrarily large, and has a minimum at $x=0.$  It doesn't look like your graph.

Comment: Let's say I want to plot the predicted probabilities of y based on values of x. I expect this relationship to not be linear but rather follow a parabolic curve for the first part but then plateau at maximum. How would I need to define my model equation to achieve this? Thank you,

Comment: Use a logit link.